# table transpose in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I trying to write sql code to create a table which is a transpose of  given table. Initially I have a table with data. I am trying to create a table which is transpose of input table using sql server management studio.

Plz help me....

input is as follows:
[image: tbl]

output :

[image: tbltr]

Answer (score 1):

Try UNPIVOT.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..... i don't need any column names and all... all I need is just to transpose the data of the given table..... If this is what pivot will do can you try to explain me for my example table.....I'm newbie to sql

Comment: By transposing, do you mean you want to rotate your table?

Comment: I just want to rotate table data...as shown in figure i.e., the first row in original table is the data for the first column of the table

Comment: Pivot and unpivot are the right approach.  As far as I know, there is no way using SQL to do this without already knowing the number and names of the columns, which is what pivot/unpivot require.

Comment: You can pivot with dynamic columns. Just search for pivot and dynamic in google and you'll get some good results. http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx was the first to turn up in my serach. I tend to use the example shown in the article that uses XML PATH. I find this works nicely.

Comment: getting the solution partially........ i added a column with values x1,x2,x3 to my initial table and then applied pivot manually for y1,..through y5....

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will probably do the trick:

**Test data**

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl 
    (
        Y1 INT,
        Y2 INT,
        Y3 INT,
        Y4 INT,
        Y5 INT
    )

INSERT INTO #tbl
VALUES
    (1,2,3,4,9),
    (1,6,9,3,6),
    (2,2,6,7,6)
```

Then we need to know how many X columns there. This gets the columns:

```
DECLARE @nbrOf INT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tbl)

DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @colsWithName VARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH Nbrs ( n ) AS (
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 + n FROM Nbrs WHERE n <@nbrOf )
SELECT
    @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ','+QUOTENAME(n),
                     QUOTENAME(n)),
    @colsWithName = COALESCE(@colsWithName + ','+QUOTENAME(n)+' AS X'+CAST(n AS VARCHAR(10)),
                     QUOTENAME(n)+' AS X'+CAST(n AS VARCHAR(10)))
FROM
    Nbrs
```

Then we are going do some dynamic sql with a pivot. Like this:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N'SELECT
    '+@colsWithName+'
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tbl.Y1) AS RowNbr,
            tbl.Y1,
            tbl.Y2,
            tbl.Y3,
            tbl.Y4,
            tbl.Y5
        FROM
            #tbl AS tbl
    ) AS p
    UNPIVOT
    (
        Value FOR Name IN 
      (Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5)
    ) AS unpvt
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Value)
        FOR RowNbr IN('+@cols+')
    ) AS pvt'
EXECUTE(@query)
```

Then in my case I will drop the temp table

```
DROP TABLE #tbl
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i found some bug in your solution. if the order of the values of column 'Y1'  is not ascending it won't work because it is using ROW_NUMBER() function over Y1.

Comment: That is true. Maybe you have a primary key? Because then we can use that in the order by. We need someone to determine what is the first and the last x value.